# What does overriding virtual function differs only by calling convention mean?

Tags: c++, com

I am trying to implement [IUnknown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I followed the instruction to the tee but it isn't working. When I try to compile I get:

```
Error   2   error C2695: 'testInterfaceImplementation::AddRef': overriding virtual function differs from 'IUnknown::AddRef' only by calling convention  c:\users\seanm\desktop\test\test\source.cpp 6   1   test
Error   3   error C2695: 'testInterfaceImplementation::QueryInterface': overriding virtual function differs from 'IUnknown::QueryInterface' only by calling convention  c:\users\seanm\desktop\test\test\source.cpp 14  1   test
Error   4   error C2695: 'testInterfaceImplementation::Release': overriding virtual function differs from 'IUnknown::Release' only by calling convention    c:\users\seanm\desktop\test\test\source.cpp 22  1   test
```

from this code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

class testInterfaceImplementation : public IUnknown {
    protected:
        ULONG AddRef() 
        {
            MessageBox(NULL,
                _T("TEST1"),
                _T("TEST1"),
                NULL);
            return 0;
        }
        HRESULT QueryInterface(IN REFIID riid, OUT void **ppvObject) 
        {
            MessageBox(NULL,
                _T("TEST2"),
                _T("TEST2"),
                NULL);
            return S_OK;
        }
        ULONG Release() {
            MessageBox(NULL,
                _T("TEST3"),
                _T("TEST3"),
                NULL);
            return 0;
        }
};
```

Comment: The error message means exactly what it says. To override a function, everything must be identical. But your override is not identical to the base function. The base function and your function have different calling conventions. Fix your function to have the same calling convention as the base function.

Comment: You shouldn't return `S_OK` from such incomplete `QI()` implementation - something like `E_FAIL` would be much better.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add `STDMETHODCALLTYPE` for each of the methods.

```
ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef() 
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(IN REFIID riid, OUT void **ppvObject) 
ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release()
```

The base class(`IUnknown`) methods are declared as `STDMETHODCALLTYPE` (which is a macro for `__stdcall`). When you override a virtual method, it has to have the same calling convention as the original which in this case is `__stdcall`